# Chat for Spring MVC webUI

Tags: spring-mvc

I am required to show stacked bar chart in my web application. The application uses JSP with spring MVC and mysql as the backend. Please suggest any easy to use charting libraries that I can use. Just have 2 charts completely in the application and hence would be helpful to have a library that would be simple to use and render in my application via my controller api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you really need is probably a JavaScript library, and your choice will depend on which base library you choose.  I have used Dojo in the past, but have recently settled on jQuery.  I think [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/) has a stacked bar chart, if I am not mistaken.  I am sure there are some open source libraries for jQuery that do charting as well.

Your other option is to generate the chart as an image and post it on your page using straight img tags, but I think that's not a very optimal way of doing things now a days.